# Shape recognition after edge detection

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on my first computer vision project where I take a picture of a chart and detect the symbols on it.  There are 5 distinct shapes that need to be detected.

This is the result of my edge detection algorithm: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CCQm.jpg.  The 5 symbols are a single dot, 4 dots grouped together, a rectangle, and 2 oddly shaped symbols.

At this point I'm not sure which algorithms I should look at that will allow me to pick out these shapes and discern them from each other.  Any ideas would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [Shape Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_context) would be a natural choice for this type of problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not implemented in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

some years ago I tried template matching with OpenCV, which is described [here.](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html?highlight=template%20matching)

It worked pretty well, and I think this is what you are looking for; however I remember that it was pretty slow, so maybe it won't be a good fit if you are programming a real time application. If this is the case, you may have to play around with the geometry of your shapes, and try to find them with [Hough transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) for [lines](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=hough#CvSeq%2a%20cvHoughLines2%28CvArr%2a%20image,%20void%2a%20line_storage,%20int%20method,%20double%20rho,%20double%20theta,%20int%20threshold,%20double%20param1,%20double%20param2%29) and [circles](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=hough#CvSeq%2a%20cvHoughCircles%28CvArr%2a%20image,%20void%2a%20circle_storage,%20int%20method,%20double%20dp,%20double%20min_dist,%20double%20param1,%20double%20param2,%20int%20min_radius,%20int%20max_radius%29), which are both implemented in OpenCV.

Have fun !